# Unable to read properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

I have a properties file in `src/main/resources`.

Spring 4.0 and Java 1.8 project.

mock.properties

```
key=test
```

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.z.*">
</context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mock.properties"
    order="-1" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Controller.java ... I can access the value of property key in controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/xyz")
public class EC2Controller {
@Value("${key}")
String v;
}
```

Helper.java  ... Can't access any property.Always gets "null"

```
@Component
public class Helper {
@Value("${key}")
String v;
}
```

I also tried various options suggested on forums and spring docs but helper is just not able to read the prop.I tried following as well

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mock.properties")
public class Helper {
@Value("${key}")
String v;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer      
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mock.properties")
public class Helper {
@Autowired
Environment env;
String v = env.getProperty("key");
}
```

nothing works.

Comment: To clarify: your @Autowire annotation is actually @Autowire**d** (with a d), correct?

Comment: I have a sample working code @ https://github.com/shaimakh/so36732090

Comment: Hi @Sanj..yes i know thats how it is supposed to work in ideal scenario.But i am unable to figure out whats going wrong in my app.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like you have all the components you need. Ugh, brings back bad memories where I struggled for a long time as well trying to get this to work.

Comment: @WillMcavoy - I took all the information from your post and it is working. Possible for you to post a sample on github?

Comment: How are you using/accessing the helper?

Comment: @Deinum ..Helper is a singleton classI have a static method which returns me an instance of it. Helper.getInstance().

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether you are using the <strike>*springonfig.xml*</strike> *mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml* that you show above. Based on your code samples, it looks like you are not (unless there is something missing).

Your *mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml* includes *context:property-placeholder*, so it should be sufficient. But if you are not using it, or want to use an @Configuration (Java config) class instead (you can mix xml and Java config in the same app) then you need a PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer to resolve ${} in @Value, such as:

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```

See documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html, which states:

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in  definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer...

Note that the documentation states this happens automatically when using context:property-placeholder in XML - but as noted it's not clear from your code samples whether you are using that.

Comment: I think `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is same with `<context:property-placeholder... ` ,the different is Java config and xml

Comment: Correct - though it's not clear from the code samples whether that is being used in the configuration (see my note above).

Comment: My bad.I have updated the question correctly now.That is the only context file i have and i believe it is begin used.My REST call gets mapped to my @Controller properly also controller is able to read the property.Problem is with helper or any other class in my app.

Comment: I had tried with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer as suggested by Woodchuck. I forgot to paste it in my question previously. It did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code snippet, and use **${key}** to inject value:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/demo.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

or this, and use **#{app.key}** to inject value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-util-3.2.xsd" profile="dev">    

    ...

    <util:properties id="app" location="app.properties" />

    ...
</beans>
```

Hope to help you.